# How to use rviz to show multiple planning paths

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, i'm doing path planing,i want to show  multiple planing paths using rviz at one time,but i find <nav_msgs::Path> message can only be showed one planning path on rviz.How shoud i do?My multiple planing paths is stored in a vector like vector<nav_msgs::Path> finalpath.Thanks for your help!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220898/how-to-use-rviz-to-show-multiple-planning-paths/) by [aids](https://answers.ros.org/users/24026/aids/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-11-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, there are four easy ways for you.

i. publish each of path

If your paths isn't too much, I suggest you set name for each of path and publish that.

ii. marker array

Follow the Javier's answer.

iii. polygon array

Install jsk_rviz_plugins and then you will can be visualize polygon array type on RViz.

http://jsk-visualization.readthedocs.org/en/latest/jsk_rviz_plugins/plugins/polygon_array.html

iv. path array

Creating new display plugin for custom path array message like nav_msgs/Path[].

http://docs.ros.org/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/display_plugin_tutorial.html

---

Originally posted by [Daiki Maekawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19960/daiki-maekawa/) with karma: 40 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aids293](https://answers.ros.org/users/26004/aids293/) on 2016-02-19**:
thank you very much,i got it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure if there is a better option, but most probably the solution is to convert from `vector<nav_msgs::path>` to a marker array using line strips or line lists.

More info [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines) (sorry I cannot find the markerarray tutorial)

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-11-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1